# No Cells Found Error on calling ClearContents in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to clear all but cells A1 and B1 as they’re my headers whilst retaining formulas in A2, B2 and C1 using the following which is called when a sheet is activated-

```
Private Sub ClearSelectSheetContents()
    Dim SheetSource As Worksheet
    Set SheetSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff Gantt")
    
    ' clear all cells barring the headers in A and B, also maintain the formulas
    SheetSource.Range("A2:B1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    SheetSource.Range("C1:XX1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
End Sub
```

However I am receiving a runtime error "1004" No cells were found. Any ideas on whether there's anything I can do to get around this please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get around"? If there's no constant cells, that's a function of the sheet/range you're working with. Typically one can test this by using `On Error Resume Next`, assigning `SheetSource.Range("A2:B1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` to a `Range` variable, then `On Error GoTo 0`, then testing `If Not rng Is Nothing`, where `rng` is the variable...

Comment: Try removing `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).`

Comment: if you want to retain a2 and b2 and c1, then why include them in the ranges.  Just do the ones you want and just clear the contents, then no need for special cells.

Comment: I meant A1 and B1, corrected in the question

Comment: you still say you want to retain the formula in a1,b2, and c1.  Just omit them from the ranges and do not use special cells.

Comment: It’s my understanding SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
Will retain the formulas. Once I can get past the error I’ll know for sure.

Comment: Hey BigBen, that worked thanks. I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Call ClearSelectSheetContents
End Sub

Private Sub ClearSelectSheetContents()
    Dim SheetSource As Worksheet
    Set SheetSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff Gantt")
    
    Dim rngA As Range

    Set rngA = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    ' clear all cells barring the headers in A and B, also maintain the formulas
    Set rngA = SheetSource.Range("A2:B1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not rngA Is Nothing Then
        rngA.ClearContents
    End If

    Dim rngB As Range

    Set rngB = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    ' clear all cells barring the headers in A and B, also maintain the formulas
    Set rngB = SheetSource.Range("C1:XX1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not rngA Is Nothing Then
        rngB.ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```